# mutation Observer not initializing/working

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have an issue with my mutationobserver and I cannot seem to understand what is going on.
my first check is to make sure mutationobserver is define and loaded on the page.
Next I create my new mutationobserver
and then if there are mutations, I wait until they are all finished and run a function.

The problem is is that the script is not create a new mutationobserver.

Here is my typical output, I only make it as far as my first console log.
//poll typeof good

On rare occasion, the mutationobserver will be created and I will get a full load of my logs, but it is 1 out of 10/20 times.  I thought it might be a timing issue, but after setting my settimeout to 10 sec, it makes me doubt there is a timing issue.

My only other note is that this is being injected onto the page as the page loads, asynchronously.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it, but figured I'd call it out

Any thoughts?

```
setTimeout(function () {

  if(window.MutationObserver && typeof MutationObserver === 'function'){

  console.log('poll typeof check');

  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

       var optFilterSort = new MutationObserver(function(entries) {
       var optEntries = entries.length;
        console.log('poll optEntries ' + optEntries);
        if(entries.length >= optEntries){
          console.log('poll mutations complete');
          optStart();
       }
    });

  var optTargetFilter = document.querySelector(".mydiv");
  var optConfig = {
        attributes: !0,
        childList: !0,
        characterData: !0,
        subtree: !0
    };
  optFilterSort.observe(optTargetFilter,optConfig);
  
  
}

}, 10000);
```

Comment: I think you are losing reference to your MutationObserver because it is within a function context.  you are literally setting a timer which delays the creation ( and lifetime of ) your observer.  Why can't you directly create your observer within your HTML or load a script? why do you think you need to wait before creating your observer? why not create it without defining any observed data, then you can call with timeout, set the observed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @ThisGuy I started without the settimeout previously and it had the same impact, which was nothing, so that's when I tried the settimout to see if it was a timing issue.  Both are having the same result

Comment: @ThisGuy I just copied the code from the page you sent and modified it to fit my selector and it worked.  So confused...What do you think it was about my code that didn't match the example you provided (outside of the setTimout?)

Comment: when you execute the setTimeout, it runs within a temporary context. using var will declare the VARiable to be removed when the function completes. so after your timeout function runs, any variables created within it are deleted. you can instead create your variable and assign it to the window object by stating "window.MutationObserver = new MutationObserver, or something like that. what you experienced is one downside of closure.  this means that your variable can't be referenced outside of the context which created it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: I highly recommend referencing developer.mozilla.org these are the folks who literally write the specs for modern web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "var optFilterSort..." exists only within the context of your function, called with the setTimeout callback function. Your created MutationObserver is effectly deleted once the setTimeout callback function has completed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver has an example for setting up a mutation observer object.  You should be setting your mutation observer as a variable of the window or within a persisting context.